# WebViewClient always reloads site

Tags: java, android, webview, reload

my WebViewClient always reloads the site it shows. It looks like a stroboscope. 
At first it gets his values from another activity, than it insert them supported by javascript and get to the "target" site. Up to this action everything is ok but then it flickers. How can I prevent that? Here's my code:

```
public class Webview extends Activity {
    WebView webView;
    String site = "xyz.com";
    private String bnm, pwd1;
    private ProgressBar bar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web_view);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        bnm = getIntent().getStringExtra("benutzername");
        pwd1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("password");
        website(site);
    }


    public void website(String website) {
        website = site;
        bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Webview.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            webView.loadUrl(site);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    String user=bnm;
                    String pwd= pwd1;
                    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('username').value = '"+user+"';document.getElementById('password').value='"+pwd+"';"+"document.getElementById('submit').click();");
                    view.loadUrl("xyz.com");
                    bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });



    }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

when `onPageFinished(...)` gets called (when the page is done loading) you call `view.loadUrl("xyz.com")` again, which reloads the page. You can create some sort of external counter to check whether you've already injected the appropriate `js` variables and not call the `loadUrl(...)` again.

Comment: Hey, the first idea was to load the page in background first, login with the variables and then show it. The secoond URL is another than the first. How do you mean that ?